# Fixed component not re-rendering when changing the profile page of a user

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, components

```
const Profile = () => {
 return(
   <div>
     <ProfileData/>
     <Switch>
       <Route exact path="/profile/:user" component={(props) => (<ProfileScreen {...props}/>)}/>
       <Route exact path="/profile/:user/followers" component={(props) => (<ProfileFollowers {...props}/>)}/>
       <Route exact path="/profile/:user/following" component={(props) => (<ProfileFollowing {...props}/>)}/>
       <Route component={NotFound}/>
     </Switch>
   </div>
 )
}
```

So, in the above route, I have a component ProfileData which contains the name and other general info about a user. This component does not re-render while navigation through the user's followers and following but now when I click on a user in the follower's section (using NavLink) the above ProfileData does not re-render and contains the information about the previous user.
What's the best method to fix this, so that the ProfileData re-renders when navigating to another user's profile page?

Comment: Does the state, used in the ProfileData component change when you click on a follower's section??

I am not sure your question is clear enough.

Comment: No, it does not change because it is in another class

Comment: Then it would probably not re-render, you might want to lift the state up into Profile and then pass down a handler method as props to ProfileFollowers, the handler method then causes that state to change. 
Or consider using redux